# Factorizing $88^2-12^2$

Tags: prime-factorization

I tried finding the square root of both sides but it is in decimal and i got the answer $2(44-6)$ but my books' answering scheme says it is $7600$ please help me!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $88^2 - 12^2 = (88+12)(88-12)$

Answer (score 1):

Using the fact that
$$(a + b)(a - b) = a^2 - b^2$$
you can rewrite the expression as
$$88^2 - 12^2 = (88 + 12)(88 - 12) = \dots$$

I'm sure you can take it from here.

Comment: Equivalence doesn't really make sense here, it's rather equality no?

Comment: @servabat: Isn't equivalence $\equiv$? I only used equality.

Comment: well, you used $\iff$, but $(a+b)(a-b) = a^2 - b^2$ : $(a+b)(a-b)$ and $a^2-b^2$ aren't logical expression.

Comment: I actually meant the `\iff` thing with equivalence.

Comment: Ah I see now. You have a point, I'll edit.